# Embedding math into Doxygen docs

Tags: formula, doxygen

I am sending a test case where the second
"\f$" item is replaced with the previous "\f["

(using 1.8.13)

(It could be some temporary filename issue:
the replacement can also be some fragment that already gone)

```
/*!
 * \f[
 * \frac{dV_m}{dt} = \sum_{i=0}^{n} g{sin,i}(t)\frac{E_{sin,i}-V_{m}}{C} + \frac{V_{rest}-V_{m}}{RC}
 * \f]
 * The routine replaces \f$ dt \f$  with \f$ \Delta t \f$
 */
```

Comment: The question lacks very important information: what is the problem, which output format is used, which other doxygen settings are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doxygen 1.8.13 is from December 2016, the current version is 1.8.20.

The question lacks very important information: what is the problem, which output format is used, which other doxygen settings are used.

Seen this it is hard to tell what goes wrong but some ideas.
Version 1.8.13 might have problems with newer versions of LaTeX (like giving: `Error: /undefinedfilename in (_form0.ps)`).

Solutions for this:

- use MathJax for rendering formulas (in HTML), by setting `USE_MATHJAX=YES`
- upgrade to a newer version of doxygen
- downgrade the LaTeX version

Comment: As I told, I submitted a short test, that shows the symptom of producing wrong HTML output.  If you see a formula twice, it is wrong. It you can run it on a newer system, it is OK for me.